# What if I want to assign a property to itself?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, properties, didset

If I attempt to run the following code:

```
photographer = photographer
```

I get the error:

> Assigning a property to itself.

---

I want to assign the property to itself to force the `photographer` `didSet` block to run.

Here's a real-life example: In the "16. Segues and Text Fields" lecture of the [Winter 2013 Stanford iOS course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016) (13:20), the professor recommends writing code similar to the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var photographerLabel: UILabel!

var photographer: Photographer? {
    didSet {
        self.title = photographer.name
        if isViewLoaded() { reload() }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    reload()
}

func reload() {
    photographerLabel.text = photographer.name
}
```

**Note**: I made the following changes: (1) the code was switched from Objective-C to Swift; (2) because it's in Swift, I use the `didSet` block of the property instead of the `setPhotographer:` method; (3) instead of `self.view.window` I am using `isViewLoaded` because the former erroneously forces the view to load upon access of the `view` property; (4) the `reload()` method (only) updates a label for simplicity purposes, and because it resembles my code more closely; (5) the photographer `IBOutlet` label was added to support this simpler code; (6) since I'm using Swift, the `isViewLoaded()` check no longer exists simply for performance reasons, it is now *required* to prevent a crash, since the IBOutlet is defined as `UILabel!` and not `UILabel?` so attempting to access it before the view is loaded will crash the application; this wasn't mandatory in Objective-C since it uses the null object pattern.

The reason we call reload twice is because we don't know if the property will be set before or after the view is created. For example, the user might first set the property, then present the view controller, or they might present the view controller, and then update the property.

I like how this property is agnostic as to when the view is loaded (it's best not to make any assumptions about view loading time), so I want to use this same pattern (only slightly modified) in my own code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var photographerLabel: UILabel?

var photographer: Photographer? {
    didSet {
        photographerLabel?.text = photographer.name
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    photographer = photographer
}
```

Here instead of creating a new method to be called from two places, I just want the code in the `didSet` block. I want `viewDidLoad` to force the `didSet` to be called, so I assign the property to itself. Swift doesn't allow me to do that, though. How can I force the `didSet` to be called?

Comment: How about `let temp = photographer; photographer = temp` ?

Comment: how about `photographerLabel?.text = oldvalue.name`

Comment: Other possibilities include  `photographer = (photographer)`, `photographer = photographer ?? nil`

Comment: So far `photographer = (photographer)` looks like the most elegant solution.

Comment: right, the brackets is a very clever and elegant solution.

Comment: So glad I found this. Anyone know the WHY of what Apple was thinking here? At most, make it a warning.

Comment: @TravisGriggs You mean by disabling code that shouts "this is unnecessary, remove me" to the next person that looks at the code?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Prior to **Swift 3.1** you could assign the property `name` to itself with:

```
name = (name)
```

but this now gives the same error: **"assigning a property to itself"**.

There are many other ways to work around this including introducing a temporary variable:

```
let temp = name
name = temp
```

This is just too fun not to be shared.  I'm sure the community can come up with many more ways to do this, the crazier the better

```
class Test: NSObject {
    var name: String? {
        didSet {
            print("It was set")
        }
    }

    func testit() {
        // name = (name)    // No longer works with Swift 3.1 (bug SR-4464)
        // (name) = name    // No longer works with Swift 3.1
        // (name) = (name)  // No longer works with Swift 3.1
        (name = name)
        name = [name][0]
        name = [name].last!
        name = [name].first!
        name = [1:name][1]!
        name = name ?? nil
        name = nil ?? name
        name = name ?? name
        name = {name}()
        name = Optional(name)!
        name = ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional(name)
        name = true ? name : name
        name = false ? name : name
        let temp = name; name = temp
        name = name as Any as? String
        name = (name,0).0
        name = (0,name).1
        setValue(name, forKey: "name") // requires class derive from NSObject
        name = Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).takeUnretainedValue().name
        name = unsafeBitCast(name, to: type(of: name))
        name = unsafeDowncast(self, to: type(of: self)).name
        perform(#selector(setter:name), with: name) // requires class derive from NSObject
        name = (self as Test).name
        unsafeBitCast(dlsym(dlopen("/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib",RTLD_NOW),"objc_msgSend"),to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector!,Any?)->Void).self)(self,#selector(setter:name),name) // requires class derive from NSObject
        unsafeBitCast(class_getMethodImplementation(type(of: self), #selector(setter:name)), to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector!,Any?)->Void).self)(self,#selector(setter:name),name) // requires class derive from NSObject
        unsafeBitCast(method(for: #selector(setter:name)),to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector,Any?)->Void).self)(self,#selector(setter:name),name) // requires class derive from NSObject 
        _ = UnsafeMutablePointer(&name)
        _ = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&name)
        _ = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: &name, count: 1)
        withUnsafePointer(to: &name) { name = $0.pointee }

        //Using NSInvocation, requires class derive from NSObject
        let invocation : NSObject = unsafeBitCast(method_getImplementation(class_getClassMethod(NSClassFromString("NSInvocation"), NSSelectorFromString("invocationWithMethodSignature:"))),to:(@convention(c)(AnyClass?,Selector,Any?)->Any).self)(NSClassFromString("NSInvocation"),NSSelectorFromString("invocationWithMethodSignature:"),unsafeBitCast(method(for: NSSelectorFromString("methodSignatureForSelector:"))!,to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector,Selector)->Any).self)(self,NSSelectorFromString("methodSignatureForSelector:"),#selector(setter:name))) as! NSObject
        unsafeBitCast(class_getMethodImplementation(NSClassFromString("NSInvocation"), NSSelectorFromString("setSelector:")),to:(@convention(c)(Any,Selector,Selector)->Void).self)(invocation,NSSelectorFromString("setSelector:"),#selector(setter:name))
        var localVarName = name
        withUnsafePointer(to: &localVarName) { unsafeBitCast(class_getMethodImplementation(NSClassFromString("NSInvocation"), NSSelectorFromString("setArgument:atIndex:")),to:(@convention(c)(Any,Selector,OpaquePointer,NSInteger)->Void).self)(invocation,NSSelectorFromString("setArgument:atIndex:"), OpaquePointer($0),2) }
        invocation.perform(NSSelectorFromString("invokeWithTarget:"), with: self)
    }
}

let test = Test()
test.testit()
```

Comment: Haha `name = true ? name : name` made me laugh.

Comment: `name = (name)` does not work as of Xcode Version 8.3 beta 2. `name = { name }()` does, however.

Comment: I think the game is over since iOS 10.3 will produce an error for many of these.

Comment: Swift authors loved this crazy stuff and banned `name = (name)` in Swift 3.1. So, let's have some fun with new ideas, because these easy ways (`name = nil ?? name` etc.) gonna be forbidden in 3.2, haha

Comment: `name = Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).takeUnretainedValue().name`
& `setValue(name, forKey: "name")`

Comment: @Kamil.S, name = (`name`) gives Error assigning a property to itself in Swift 3.1.  `setValue(name, forKey: "name")` only works if Test class derives from `NSObject`.

Comment: Good point, I was testing on UIViewController, I corrected the answer for both cases.

Answer (score 16):

There are some good workarounds but there is little point in doing that.
If a programmer (future maintainer of the code) sees code like this:

```
a = a
```

They will remove it.

Such a statement (or a workaround) should never appear in your code.

If your property looks like this:

```
var a: Int {
   didSet {
      // code
   }
}
```

then it's a not a good idea to invoke the `didSet` handler by assignment `a = a`.

What if a future maintainer adds a performance improvement to the `didSet` like this?

```
var a: Int {
   didSet {
      guard a != oldValue else {
          return
      }

      // code
   }
}
```

The real solution is to refactor:

```
var a: Int {
   didSet {
      self.updateA()
   }
}

fileprivate func updateA() {
   // the original code
}
```

And instead of `a = a` directly call `updateA()`.

If we are speaking about outlets, a suitable solution is to force the loading of views before assigning for the first time:

```
@IBOutlet weak var photographerLabel: UILabel?

var photographer: Photographer? {
    didSet {
        _ = self.view // or self.loadViewIfNeeded() on iOS >= 9

        photographerLabel?.text = photographer.name // we can use ! here, it makes no difference
    }
}
```

That will make the code in `viewDidLoad` unnecessary.

Now you might be asking *"why should I load the view if I don't need it yet? I want only to store my variables here for future use"*. If that's what you are asking, it means you are using a view controller as your model class, just to store data. That's an architecture problem by itself. If you don't want to use a controller, don't even instantiate it. Use a model class to store your data.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I hope one day #Swift developers will fix this *miscuzzi :)*

**Simple crutch:**

```
func itself<T>(_ value: T) -> T {
    return value
}
```

**Use:**

```
// refresh
style = itself(style)
image = itself(image)
text  = itself(text)
```

**(optionals including)**

---

Answer (score 2):

Make a function that the didSet calls then call that function when you want to update something? Seems like this would guard against developers going WTF? in future

Answer (score 1):

[@vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31931318/4153728) did a great job with all those options. However in *iOS 10.3*, Apple banned some of these ways and most likely will be doing it in the future again.

> **Note:** To avoid the risk and future errors, I will use a temporary variable.

---

#### We can create a simple function for that:

```
func callSet<T>(_ object: inout T) {
    let temporaryObject = object
    object = temporaryObject
}
```

Would be used like: `callSet(&foo)`

---

#### Or even a unary operator, if there is a fitting one ...

```
prefix operator +=

prefix func +=<T>(_ object: inout T) {
    let temporaryObject = object
    object = temporaryObject
}
```

Would be used like: `+=foo`

Comment: That's a completely crazy solution for a simple architecture problem.

Comment: That is your point of view. E.g. In your answer you are creating a function every time you create a property for that purpose. You can end up with tons of these and it's fine. But someone does not have to prefer this way. And it is not an architecture problem, it is a feature after all.

Comment: It's a code readability problem. It's a way to invoke the side-effect of an assignment without assignment. That screams "bad code".

Comment: Indeed, and did you read the question? "What if I want to assign a property to itself?". You could simply say "do not do that because it leads to the readability problem", and you would have right, no doubt about it.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is "don't do it". I am answering the underlying problem instead :)

Comment: By the way, from the discussion on swift.org I gather that banning `a = (a)` was unintended an it will probably return someday.