# Why does Swift allow assigning a struct property to itself, but not a class property?

Tags: swift

Swift has this awesome error that shows up when you try to do something of the form `x = x`:

```
class Foo {
    var foo = 1
}

var a = Foo()
a.foo = a.foo // error
```

This helped me avoid typos where the class had two similarly named properties, and I want to assign one to the other, but mistakenly typed the same one twice.

However, in this particular case:

```
struct Foo {
    var foo = 1 {
        didSet {
            print("Did set")
        }
    }

    mutating func f() {
        foo = foo
    }
}

var a = Foo()
a.foo = a.foo
```

It successfully compiles! There isn't even an error on the `foo = foo` line! If I change `Foo` to a class, or if I remove the `didSet`, then the expected error appears. It's just this struct + `didSet` combination that makes the compiler think "yeah, `a.foo = a.foo` makes a lot of sense! Let me allow that!"

I found [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31930257/5133585), which is about how to *stop* getting this error, rather than how *to* get it.

I also [looked](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4464?jql=text%20%7E%20%22assigning%20property%20to%20itself%22) on bugs.swift.org, but there were only 3 results, and none of them are related.

I'm using Swift 5.3.2 and Xcode 12.4.

Is there any reason why assigning a struct property to itself is *more* "OK" than assigning a class property to itself?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error... Simply pasting this into a playground gives the expected error. Is there anything missing? What swift version are you using?

Comment: @Schottky I mentioned the Swift version in the question. Time to update Xcode again, huh...

Comment: Oops didn't see, sorry. I was using Xcode 12.5 so that might indeed be the issue

Comment: Is the function f() inside foo property observer? Or is it just a typo?

Comment: I tried testing your code in project itself and not in playground, and it’s giving me the same error as with class. I am using Xcode 12.5 though. Verified with playground, still same error. Seems it’s specific to Xcode 12.4.

Comment: Interesting if you add this line ```var a = Foo()``` outside the function and within class level it will not throw an error.